# How to count the number of rows that have the value 1 for all the columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following is an example dataframe for this issue:

```
name    gender    address    phone no.
---------------------------------------
1       1         1          1
1       0         0          0
1       1         1          1
1       1         0          1
```

The desired output here is **2** because the number of rows containing all **1s** is **2**.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`eq(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to identify the values with 1, then aggregate per row with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to have `True` when all values are `True` and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) the `True` taking advantage of the `True`/`1` equivalence:

```
df.eq(1).all(axis=1).sum()
```

output: `2`

Intermediates:

```
df.eq(1)
   name  gender  address  phone no.
0  True    True     True       True
1  True   False    False      False
2  True    True     True       True
3  True    True    False       True

df.eq(1).all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: is there a way to get all the rows that have the value '1' in a separate dataframe? @mozmay

Comment: @VineethSai yes, but with a different method (maybe `merge` or `isin`), please open a new question if needed

Comment: yes, could you please provide the code snippet for the same? because I'm unable to open a new question because it says that I have to wait for 90 minutes now. thanks. @mozway

Comment: The thing is that the code will depend on your exact data, I suggest you prepare the reproducible input and let me know when you can post.

Comment: First read [merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) carefully

Comment: why merge tho? i mean, i only need the values that have 1 in all the columns in the dataframe. that's all. @mozway

Comment: @VineethSai but are the two dataframes the same shape and aligned? In this case a simple `df1[df2['col'].eq(1).to_numpy()]` will do

Comment: actually, there is no 2nd dataframe. there is only one as mentioned above. i have to just store the rows that have value 1 in a different dataframe. i hope you understood this now. @mozway

Answer (score 1):

Let's do

```py
l = sum(df.eq(1).all(axis=1))
```

```
print(l)

2
```

Comment: is there a way to get all the rows that have the value '1' in a separate dataframe? @Ynjxsjmh

Answer (score 1):

Assuming above dataframe is a binary table i.e. all values are either `1` or `0`, then `df.sum(axis=1)` equal to `4` should give you all rows where all values are `1`.

```py
df[df.sum(axis=1) == len(df.columns)]

   name  gender  address  phone no.
0     1       1        1          1
2     1       1        1          1
```